# CombineReducers and good structure in react-redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, structure, react-redux

I made calendar part of app, and also tried to make it can be reusable.

Then I also made another part using calendar.

So I used combineReducers function.

```
import calendar from '../../common/calendar/Reducer';
import insatester from './Reducer';

const reducerCombiner = combineReducers({
    calendar,
    insatester
});
export default reducerCombiner
```

Then, I used the combined reducer to make a store.

It seems to work fine first.
But the store and data was separated.

example)

store.calendar.data1 <- from calendar

store.insatester.data2 <- from insatester

Then I tried to get calendar event DB data from insatester, because I think reusable calendar doesn't do that.
But the problem is using stored db data from calendar app also need to access store.insatester, it doesn't make sense.

Question1. How can I combine reducers to make the store having same level?

example)

store.data1 <- from calendar

store.data2 <- from insatester

Question2. Is my structure having problems? How can I change it?

Comment: So, you need to access data in components or reducers?

Comment: in calendar component, but need to access data in store.insatester. So it looks weird for reusing component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write a reducer that can access the full state. As you've seen, `combineReducers` limits you to a single slice of the state. You can put your custom reducer in front to handle the actions that need data from both slices, and let the rest fall into the `combineReducers` part.

This page of the Redux docs explains: http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/BeyondCombineReducers.html#sharing-data-between-slice-reducers